# Q: Error when installing "node-red-contrib-composer" using "Manage Palette" feature

Tags: hyperledger-composer

When I try to install the plugin using the "Manage Palette" feature of node-red the installation fails with a general error: "Error: stderr maxBuffer exceeded". The work-around for me was to install the plugin from the command line inside the `.node-red` user settings directory.

Note beyond, I am able to install other plugins via "Manage Palette" without problems. So, I don't think it is a general issue with my setup or the way I am using node-red.

So I am wondering, if I am missing something or this is a bug?

Here is how to reproduce the issue:

- Install hyperledger composer and fabric as described in the [development guide](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html) - I am using Ubuntu LTS 16.04.3 (64-bit) and Node.js 8.9.1
- Allow unprivileged users for installing global npm packages  (this one is missing in the development guide, btw!) - I used [npm-g_nosudo](https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo) for the setup
- Install node-red - Execute `npm install -g node-red` as  unprivileged user (no need for `--unsafe-perm` at this point)
- Start node-red - Execute `node-red` on the command line with the user account used to run hyperledger composer and fabric
- Try to install the `node-red-contrib-composer`plugin using "Manage Palette"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, see
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2793

and is due to this issue in node-red
https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/1488

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Actually, the issue has been reported last week when I also ran into the issue.